# How to assign students to the right school based on multiple criteria

Tags: algorithm

I need help to find the best algorithm/decision model (sorry I don't know how to call that precisely) to solve the following problem.
I have students living in a town, multiple schools in the town, and I need to assign each student to a school so that we achieve the "best combination of criteria".
The criteria are for example:

- a diversity (boys/girls) close to the diversity of the group (i.e. not all the boys together)
- distance to the school
- age of the student
- and there could be more criteria in the future

What I need is not the solution, that's why for example the exact list of criteria does not matter yet.
What I need is more an advice on what are the possible ways to solve this problem.
The "only" way I can think of at the moment is to write an algorithm to try all the possible combinations of students & schools and somehow calculate a score of each combination (each criteria would have a "weight") and then pick the solutions with the best scores. But with this approach, the amount of combination can be quite huge if we take for example 1000 students and 5 schools. So maybe there are other ways to do it.
Programming language is not important at the moment.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

Comment: My first intuition on this is that you might need 2 sets of criteria. 1. from the perspective of the student (distance to school, ...) and 2. from the perspective of the school (age, diversity,...). I feel, there is a good chance that having those 2 perspectives can help make it computationally easier. For 1. you could could do a ranking of favorite schools per student, for 2. you could then subsequently pick and choose students, taking into account rankings (Students A and B equally attractive for school but A prefers school...)

Comment: *"calculate a score [...]  and then pick the solutions with the best scores"* is pretty much the definition of a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm). The only difference is that you don't try all possible combinations. Instead you create a small pool of combinations, and then improve those solutions until you have an acceptable result.

Comment: More generally, starting with a random solution, and then improving it is known as [hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). You could, for example, assign the students randomly to the schools. Then find the most miserable student in one school, and swap that student with the most miserable student at another school. Each swap will improve the overall quality of the solution. Keep swapping until you reach an acceptable solution.

Comment: If you look for the field of science which deals with such problems, you will find it at the intersection of economics and computer science under the title "Operations Research". I think your problem falls under the topic of assignment problem in OR terms.

Comment: Thank both, I think I now see how this should be approach :) Indeed, checking all possible combination is not possible

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear optimization problem, usually solved with the Simplex algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm